# Authenticating Google Cloud Speech via GRPC on Android using an API key

Tags: android, google-cloud-speech

I've managed to get Google Cloud Speech working for my Android app using a service account in streaming mode via GRPC. However, according to what I've read, I shouldn't deploy an Android app with these credentials in them (currently stored as a JSON file in a resource) for security reasons. The correct thing is to create an API key, as described here: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/common/auth

This allows me to restrict access to my specific Android app. However, I have been unable to find out how to use the API Key from GRPC. I'm currently creating a `GoogleCredentials` instance from the JSON file, and this works fine. How can I get a credentials object from the API Key?

Answer (score 8):

you can try this with the API key

```
Metadata.Key<String> API_KEY = Metadata.Key.of("x-goog-api-key", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);

Metadata apiKeyMetadata = new Metadata();
apiKeyMetadata.put(API_KEY, yourApiKey);

final ManagedChannel channel = new OkHttpChannelProvider()
    .builderForAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT)
    .nameResolverFactory(new DnsNameResolverProvider())
    .intercept(MetadataUtils.newAttachHeadersInterceptor(apiKeyMetadata))
    .build();
speechStub = SpeechGrpc.newStub(channel);
```

Comment: applied this, getting android io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked., is there a header for application package ?

Comment: found the solution need to add X-Android-Package and X-Android-Cert needed to be added.

Comment: curious, what was the value you used for X-Android-Cert in the MetaData for the header? I can get teh android package name. but not sure fore cert ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find any Android example. However, the sample iOS client sets up a gRPC connection using the API key. It puts the key in the request header. You can try translating the iOS code into Android.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/Objective-C/Speech-gRPC-Streaming/Speech/SpeechRecognitionService.m#L59

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do this in Kotlin. Including how to pass package and signature for a restricted key.

```
    private fun signatureDigest(sig: android.content.pm.Signature): String? {

        val signature: ByteArray = sig.toByteArray()

        return try {
            val md: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1")
            val digest: ByteArray = md.digest(signature)
            BaseEncoding.base16().lowerCase().encode(digest)
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            null
        }
    }

    fun getSignature(pm: PackageManager, packageName: String?): String? {
        return try {
            val packageInfo: PackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
            if (packageInfo == null || packageInfo.signatures == null || packageInfo.signatures.size === 0 || packageInfo.signatures.get(0) == null) {
                null
            } else signatureDigest(packageInfo.signatures.get(0))
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            null
        }
    }

    private fun createConnection() {

        val packageName: String = mActivity.packageName
        val signature = getSignature(mActivity.packageManager, packageName)

        val API_KEY = Metadata.Key.of("X-Goog-Api-Key", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER)
        val BUNDLE = Metadata.Key.of("X-Android-Package", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER)
        val SIGN = Metadata.Key.of("X-Android-Cert", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER)

        val apiKeyMetadata = Metadata()
        apiKeyMetadata.put(API_KEY, "YOUR_API_KEY")
        apiKeyMetadata.put(BUNDLE, packageName)
        apiKeyMetadata.put(SIGN, signature)

        val channel = OkHttpChannelProvider()
                .builderForAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT)
                .nameResolverFactory(DnsNameResolverProvider())
                .intercept(MetadataUtils.newAttachHeadersInterceptor(apiKeyMetadata))
                .build()
        mApi = SpeechGrpc.newStub(channel)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the access token, you can use this method:

```
        final GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = new GoogleCredentials(accessToken) {
            @Override
            public AccessToken refreshAccessToken() throws IOException {
                return accessToken;
            }
        }.createScoped(OAUTH2_SCOPES);
```

You need to override the `refreshAccessToken()` as it's currently not supported.