# How to use API Key in Google Speech grpc Java library

Tags: java, grpc, google-speech-api

How do I use an API Key in Google Speech grpc Java or any other library. For HTTP request I am able to see that we can append key=API_KEY as mentioned in
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys.

But for the given libraries (https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java) all examples show how to use the Credential file.

Please help.

Comment: I *suspect* that the gRPC endpoint for Speech doesn't support API key authentication. (I'm not sure what it would look like.) I don't know for sure though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authenticating Google Cloud Speech via GRPC on Android using an API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060656/authenticating-google-cloud-speech-via-grpc-on-android-using-an-api-key)

Answer (score 0):

Use metadata with a key of X-Goog-Api-Key. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44884023/4690866). If you have API restrictions, you may need additional headers. For example, an iOS example [mentioned a bundle id restriction](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/blob/74a50ca/speech/Objective-C/Speech-gRPC-Streaming/Speech/SpeechRecognitionService.m#L58).